# Creating games for wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

i'm new to wp7 and want to develop 3d games. please help...

Comment: Refer this- http://create.msdn.com/enUS/education/catalog/article/wp7_jump_start
or download some samples like Tic Tac Toe!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest starting here: http://create.msdn.com/en-US/

That at least will get you the tools you need for this platform.
You will also want to familiarize yourself with both C# and Xaml languages.

Edit: Almost forgot.  XNA is probably going to be your friend too if you are headed for game development.  I rather like it as a framework since its fairly easy to port stuff back and forth from pc to xbox.  Never used it with wp7 but....good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

On [this](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/) website you can find all what you need.